# Parsing DateTime to Universal Time C#

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-3.5

I have a xml which can return a time in the format (7/23/2013 4:00pm) my question is: How can I explain to DateTime.ParseExact that I'm in the "am" or in the "pm"? I have this piece of code, but it returns me an exception (String can not be parsed)

I alredy placed an example string (7/23/2013 4:00pm) in which I replace "pm" by the empty chain "".

```
string pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm 'UTC' zzz";
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(sb.ToString(), pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                      DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |
                                                      DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass an array to cover various formats.  I use the following for various time inputs.

```
var formats = new[] 
    {
        "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt",
        "M/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt",
        "M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt",
        "M/dd/yyyy h:mmtt",
        "M/dd/yyyy hhtt",
        "M/dd/yyyy htt",
        "M/dd/yyyy h tt",
        "M/dd/yyyy hh tt"
    };

    var date = "7/23/2013 4:00pm";

    DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(date, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                  DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |
                                                  DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Comment: That, is awesome :D just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You need the `tt` format:

```
string pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm 'UTC' tt";
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(sb.ToString(), pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                      DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |
                                                      DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Comment: Yup, I thought that, but when the date is for example (11:15pm)? the pattern H:mm won't work, isn't it? and the difference between am and pm? :S Thank you in advance :)

Comment: try using h instead of H.

Answer (score 0):

`H` in your pattern expects the time in a 24 style. You need `tt` (as outlined in the previous answer) AND you must a small `h` in your pattern:

```
string pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm 'UTC' tt";
```

Comment: the "tt" must match with "am" or "pm" isn't it?